# Bluetooth classic / 3.0 in react native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

does anybody have experience with Bluetooth classic (3.0) in react native?

I found libraries for BLE (Bluetooth low energy) like react-native-ble-plx but nothing for classic really.

Comment: Shameless plug https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic which works on both Android and IOS (mfi).